# Записать данные в файл в два столбца

Tags: c++, файлы, вывод, fstream

Хочу записать данные в файл, но не знаю как сделать так, чтобы записывалось в два столбика.
Помогите разобраться.

....

```
mas[0]=1;
mas[1]=2;
mas[2]=3;
//...
mas[7]=8
ofstream out ("1.txt", ios::app);
for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
{
 out << mas[i] << endl;
}
out.close();
```

Comment: Наподобие `printf("%10d  %10d\n",a[i],b[i])`. Или `cout << setw(10) << a[i] << setw(10) << b[i] << "\n";` А вообще - вопрос надо задавать конкретно, а не "сделайте мне красиво". Какие данные, в каком виде представлены, в каком виде записывать...

Comment: я не говорил сделайте мне красиво)
простые числа.
Записать в виде столбца.Я думаю лучше через массив.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код, где эти данные создаются.

Comment: Я привел код, это тривиальный пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов записи массива в файл в два столбца:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include<array>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 10> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    ofstream fout("file.txt");

    bool lineEnd = true;
    for (int elem : arr)
    {
        if (lineEnd)
            fout << elem << "\t";
        else
            fout << elem << "\n";
        lineEnd = !lineEnd;
    }

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

В файл будут записаны числа из массива в два столбца.

Что здесь происходит: `"\t"` – знак табуляции, выравнивает столбцы. `"\n"` – знак перехода на новую строку. Эти спецсимволы поочерёдно добавляются после каждого выводимого элемента, что и проводит к образованию ровных столбцов.

В коде используется `std::array` вместо "голых" массивов C++, согласно настоятельным рекомендациям авторов Cpp core guidlines.

Если всё же переписать Ваш код:

```cpp
mas[0]=1;
mas[1]=2;
mas[2]=3;
//...
mas[7]=8
ofstream out ("1.txt", ios::app);
bool lineEnd = true;
for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
{
    if (lineEnd)
        out << mas[i] << "\t";
    else
        out << mas[i] << endl;
    lineEnd = !lineEnd;
}
out.close();
```

Однако рекомендую всё же пользоваться `std::array`.

Comment: Спасибо большое,очень помогли, учту рекомендации.
Можете подсказать :как мне можно считать эти числа  из файла(из столбцов) в консоль например?

Comment: @user340224 Если по-простому – читаете по строке и учитываете, что вместо пробела там стоит `'\t'`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую